# Jenkins pipeline job wont finish in the UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The issue at hand is that a jenkins pipeline job does run and finish normally. But in the UI the job stays until we abort him via the UI. This doesnt appear to often, maybe in 5% of the jobs. It might be a jenkins bug, a problem with reload configuration or just to much traffic on the nodes. I am really not sure. Since all of the "buggy" jobs have a striped progress bar this might be a clue.

What excactly does a striped progress bar mean?

[image: normal progress bar]

[image: striped progress bar]

Any other suggestions about the source of this bug is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described phenomen is caused by the reload jenkins configuration from disk option. We do this to update and change jobs. If there are pipeline jobs running during the reload, these jobs appear running as long as they dont get closed by hand. They still finish and you can see the result of the job if you open it. But in the overview these jobs become "ghost" jobs.